# Any way to create a permanent JUnit config. on IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit5, spring-boot-test

I try to test my spring boot application via JUnit 5.

The test methods need some environment variables. Even I put them on the list, each test method creates a new JUnit config so I have to put them again.

I saw [the document](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-junit.html#configTab) on JetBrains.
I can not save the JUnit config. because each config. depends on the method.

Is there any way to create a permanent  JUnit config. on IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0):

You may edit the Junit run configuration in the "Run configuration templates for new projects":
[image]

Comment: Thank you. But this does not work for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **bad idea**.  Setting up your environment variables in something like IntelliJ will make this unportable or unrunnable in a Jenkins environment.

Because you're using Spring Boot, you have more flexibility than you realize.  Rework your code so that the environment variables can be injected in through application properties.  Then, you can add the application properties to your test through the [`@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html#properties--) annotation.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.